# How to ensure a variable gets into local scope?

Tags: python, local-variables

I have a situation where I want to pass all local variables to a function in Python. However, for some reason when updating the local variables, the variable is not in scope. Is this an issue of PyCharm's interpreter, or am I missing fundamental here?

Here is some pseudo code of what I am currently doing:

```
def someFunction():
    # Create local variable
    my_local_variable = 'Hello World'

    # Create a dictionary of all local variables
    my_local_vars = dict(locals())

    # Call my function with the dictionary
    myOtherFunction(**my_local_vars)

def myOtherFunction(**args):
    locals().update(args)

    print(my_local_variable)
```

Any thoughts?

Edit: Since there are questions around why I need the functionality, here is the larger problem:

I have a code generator that needs to generate the equivalent of switch functionality. They way I have done so is to implement a switch using a dictionary, like so:

```
def GeneratedFunction(self):
    # Variable I want in scope
    (my_local_variable) = Some_other_function()

    # Begin Switch Statement: switch_SwitchDictionary_user_choice
    switch_SwitchDictionary_user_choice = {}
    switch_SwitchDictionary_user_choice["Choice 1"] = self.SwitchConnector_user_choice_is__Choice_1_
    switch_SwitchConnector_user_choice["default"] = self.SwitchConnector_user_choice_is__default_

    _localvars = dict(locals())
    del _localvars['self']
    if not (user_choice in switch_SwitchConnector_user_choice):
        (returnVals) = switch_SwitchConnector_user_choice["default"](**_localvars)
    else:
        (returnVals) = switch_SwitchConnector_user_choice[user_choice](**_localvars)
    locals().update(returnVals)
```

Comment: `locals()`: *__Note:__ The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter.*

Comment: Agreed... but what is the "better" way of getting a variable in scope?

Comment: Why not simply `args['my_local_variable']`? Much saner to begin with.

Comment: This was a simplified example. In my real code, I don't know ahead of time the variable names... as this is dynamic code. I prefer to try to have all the variables in scope be passed to the function.

Comment: @deceze is right, `my_local_variable = args['my_local_variable']` will work

Comment: If you don't even know the variables names, then you should *definitely* not be toying around with local variables. *Inspect the contents of a `dict` instead.*

Comment: so what do you wanna do with objects which names you don't know?

Comment: Bigger picture: This has to do with me making an equivalent of a switch statement, I'll update the question with more of the "code" around the method. However, since I am using a dictionary for the functions, I don't have a clean way of ensuring that all variables in the parent function stay in scope during the switch.

Comment: Mmm, yeah, no, still not seeing it. Use a `dict`.

Comment: The issue is I don't know ahead of time the variables that the user of my code generator will use, and need to be in scope. I have added my switch statement code that I generate (simplified). Is there a better way to implement a switch so that I don't have to pass the variables to/from the called methods?

Comment: A `defaultdict` whose default value is a closure of those variables?

Answer (score 0):

**Before you continue, note the following:**

Editing local variables in the way that you want to is **not** recommended and you should proceed with caution, it would be a far better option to refactor your code suitably so that you can use another technique such as a dictionary or access the variables directly from `args`.

---

This is a bad route to go down but I've answered a similar question before, you can't edit `locals` in the same way as you can `globals`:

```
def someFunction():
    my_local_variable = 'Hello World'
    my_local_vars = locals()
    myOtherFunction(my_local_vars)

def myOtherFunction(args):
    for arg in args:
        locals()[arg] = args[arg]
    print(locals())

someFunction()
```

This will result in:

```
{'arg': 'my_local_variable', 'args': {'my_local_variable': 'Hello World'}, 'my_local_variable': 'Hello World'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 12, in <module>
  File "python", line 4, in someFunction
  File "python", line 10, in myOtherFunction
NameError: name 'my_local_variable' is not defined
```

Showing that you can indeed edit `locals`, but the variable will not be available afterwards **however** this does work with `globals`:

```
def someFunction():
    my_local_variable = 'Hello World'
    my_local_vars = locals()
    myOtherFunction(my_local_vars)

def myOtherFunction(args):
    for arg in args:
        globals()[arg] = args[arg]
    print(my_local_variable)

someFunction()
print(my_local_variable)
```

which will print:

```
Hello World
Hello World
```

If you don't want to pollute the `global` scope (AND YOU SHOULDN'T), you can remove them at the end of the function:

```
def someFunction():
    my_local_variable = 'Hello World'
    my_local_vars = locals()
    myOtherFunction(my_local_vars)

def myOtherFunction(args):
    for arg in args:
        globals()[arg] = args[arg]
    print(my_local_variable)

    ...
    # Do stuff
    ...

    for arg in args:
        del globals()[arg]

someFunction()
print(my_local_variable)
```

prints:

```
Hello World
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 19, in <module>
NameError: name 'my_local_variable' is not defined
```

Alternatives would be preferred, including using a dictionary instead or, nesting your functions:

```
def someFunction():
    def myOtherFunction():
        print(my_local_variable)
    my_local_variable = 'Hello World'
    myOtherFunction()

someFunction()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to encapsulate your switcher in an object and send or capture local variables into a container of that object.
This is most secure way of doing this and not messing up anything accidentally.
Then you have only one global variable that contains a switcher object, and use it to do the switch checks and stuff safely and nicely.
You can even use different switchers for different cases and you can use them also locally if needed.

Must I tell you that doing this is risky anyway and should be avoided? Creating variables dynamically as well. You should use dictionaries for such stuff.
Messing with interpreter in such a way is not wise unless you know perfectly well what you are doing.
I am not even sure whether it is morally correct to show you how digging through interpreter stack is done.  :D  Feels like a violation of trust somehow. :D

```
from thread import get_ident
import sys

class switcher:
    def __init__ (self, vrs={}):
        self.vrs = vrs.copy() # Copy them for security
        self.__call__ = self.vrs.get
        self.clear = self.vrs.clear
        self.__getitem__ = self.vrs.__getitem__
        self.__delitem__ = self.vrs.__delitem__
        self.keys = self.vrs.keys

    def fill (self, **kwargs):
        """
        Manually fill the switcher().
        If the switcher() is not new and you wish to use only here specified cases, use switcher.clear before fill().
        """
        self.vrs.update(kwargs)

    def autofill (self, clr=0):
        """
        This method fills the switch flags with local variables defined in a scope from which it was called.
        Variables inserted will be only those defined before calling switcher.autofill()
        If you want to use only cases specified in these variables, set clr to True or
        use switcher.clear() before calling this function.
        Note: Variables containing switcher() instances won't be copied.
        """
        if clr: self.clear()
        tid = get_ident() # Thread safe
        # Get interpreter frame from which autofill() was called:
        lastfrm = sys._current_frames()[tid].f_back
        # Snatch locals() in there and populate self.vrs:
        for x in lastfrm.f_locals:
            # Prevent adding ourselves to switches.
            # If user insists uponit let him/her use switcher.fill() first.
            if isinstance(lastfrm.f_locals[x], switcher):
                continue
            self.vrs[x] = lastfrm.f_locals[x]

    def transfer (self, namespace=None):
        """
        This method transfers variables saved in the switcher()'s container into the namespace dictionary.
        Meant to use as this:
        switcher.transfer(locals())
        or
        switcher.transfer(globals())
        If namespace dictionary is not given or is None (default), variables will be transfered to a scope from which switcher.transfer() was called.
        Be careful with this method. Overwriting variables with a same name from another scope may be disasterous.
        Use switcher.keys() to check the names and del switcher[""] before calling this method to prevent overwriting existing variables.
        """
        if not namespace:
            tid = get_ident() # Thread safe
            # Get interpreter frame from which transfer() was called:
            lastfrm = sys._current_frames()[tid].f_back
            # Snatch locals() in there
            namespace = lastfrm.f_locals
        for x in self.vrs:
            namespace[x] = self.vrs[x]

# Usage:
switch = switcher()

def somefunc (somearg=1234, otherarg=False):
    blablavar = "blabla"
    def funcyfunc (arg=None):
        print "Some switch option"
        if arg: print arg
    switch.autofill(True)
    otherfunc()

def otherfunc ():
    if switch("otherarg"):
        print "yeeeey!!!!"
    switch("funcyfunc")(12345)
    print switch["blablavar"]
    print switch("somearg")

somefunc()
somefunc(otherarg=True)
switch.transfer()
funcyfunc("I just got inserted into the global scope!!!! Finally free!")

As switcher() creates an object you can pass its pointer around instead of making it global:

def funcone ():
    abc = 123
    cde = 456
    sw = switcher()
    sw.autofill()
    functwo(sw)

def functwo (switch):
    print switch.keys()
```